# C++ regex string capture

Tags: c++, regex, visual-studio, boost, g++

Tring to get C++ regex string capture to work.  I have tried all four combinations of Windows vs. Linux, Boost vs. native C++ 0x11.  The sample code is:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
//#include <regex>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    smatch sm1;
    regex_search(string("abhelloworld.jpg"), sm1, regex("(.*)jpg"));
    cout << sm1[1] << endl;
    smatch sm2;
    regex_search(string("hell.g"), sm2, regex("(.*)g"));
    cout << sm2[1] << endl;
}
```

The closest that works is g++ (4.7) with Boost (1.51.0).  There, the first cout outputs the expected `abhelloworld.` but nothing from the second cout.

g++ 4.7 with -std=gnu++11 and `<regex>` instead of `<boost/regex.hpp>` produces no output.

Visual Studio 2012 using native `<regex>` yields an exception regarding incompatible string iterators.

Visual Studio 2008 with Boost 1.51.0 and `<boost/regex.hpp>` yields an exception regarding "Standard C++ Libraries Invalid argument".

Are these bugs in C++ regex, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are these bugs in C++ regex, or am I doing something wrong?

At the time of your posting, gcc didn't support `<regex>` as noted in the other answer ([it does now](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23476206/111307)). As for the other problems, your problem is you are passing **temporary string objects**. Change your code to the following:

```
smatch sm1;
string s1("abhelloworld.jpg");
regex_search(s1, sm1, regex("(.*)jpg"));
cout << sm1[1] << endl;
smatch sm2;
string s2("hell.g");
regex_search(s2, sm2, regex("(.*)g"));
cout << sm2[1] << endl;
```

Your original example compiles because `regex_search` takes a const reference which temporary objects can bind to, however, `smatch` only stores iterators into your temporary object which no longer exists. The solution is to not pass temporaries.

If you look in the C++ standard at [§ 28.11.3/5], you will find the following:

> Returns: The result of regex_search(s.begin(), s.end(), m, e, flags).

What this means is that internally, only *iterators* to your passed in string are used, so if you pass in a temporary, iterators to that temporary object will be used which are invalid and the actual temporary itself is *not stored*.

Answer (score 0):

GCC doesn't support `<regex>` yet. Refer to the [Manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011)

Comment: as of gcc4.9, c++11 <regex> is supported.