# What part of regex is supported by GCC 4.9?

Tags: regex, c++11, gcc4.9

I don't get this. GCC is supposed to support  but accoriding to their
http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.tr1

Status page  "7 Regular Expressions are not supported".

But then at "28 Regular expressions" - they are checked as supported

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011

Could you please explain what is actually the standard and what is not?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it, but guessing from the docs you gave it seems that one of the standard is dated from 2005 and the other (the one allowing regex) is dated from 2011 and requires the `-std=gnu++11` flag to be used.

Answer (score 7):

GCC 4.9 does indeed support the C++11 `<regex>` functionality but not the tr1 version.  Note that the difference is that parts (all?) of the latter exist within a `tr1::` namespace while the C++11 `<regex>` is within namespace `std`.  There's not much point to going backwards and adding in tr1 support when C++11 has been published for some time now.

Answer (score 4):

Following information can be found from GCC 4.9 release [notes](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/04/gcc-4.9.0):

"Support for various C++14 additions have been added to the C++ Front End, on the standard C++ library side the ***most important addition is support for the C++11 regex***"

If you want to install the latest GCC4.9 version to try by yourself you can follow below SO link:

[How do I compile and run GCC 4.9.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312047/how-do-i-compile-and-run-gcc-4-9-0)

Here is the sample program which has compiled using gcc4.9 and subsequent run.

```
//Sample Program
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    regex  reg("[0-9]+");
    if (regex_match("123000", reg)) {
        cout << "It's a match!" <<endl;
    }
 return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $g++ -std=c++11 foo.cpp -o foo
> $ g++ -v
> Using built-in specs.
> COLLECT_GCC=/home/mantosh/gcc-4.9.0/bin/g++
> COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/mantosh/gcc-4.9.0/libexec/gcc/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/4.9.0/lto-wrapper
> Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
> Configured with: /home/mantosh/objdir/../gcc-4.9.0/configure --disable-multilib --prefix=/home/mantosh/gcc-4.9.0
> Thread model: posix
> gcc version 4.9.0 (GCC)
> ```

```
$ ./foo
It's a match!
```