# std::regex_error exception thrown at runtime

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

Given that this code works:

```
regex r1{ "fish"s };
smatch m1;
if (regex_search("I love fish and chips"s, m1, r1))
    cout << m1[0] << endl;
```

I believe that VS2015 supports regular expressions. However, initialization of this regular expression object:

```
regex r{ R"(\d{2,3}(-\d\d) { 2 })" };
```

throws a `std::regex_error` exception. What's wrong with the initialization?

Comment: Try to replace `{ 2 }` (plus the space left from `{`) with `{2}` or `-` with `\-`.

Comment: @Xufox wow, dude, you are absolutely correct! This part of the regexp (-\d\d) { 2 } needed to be written as (-\d\d){2}

Comment: @Xufox thank you :) I spent a hour on this tiny tiny mistake.

Comment: @NikolayZhulikov: Just for your knowledge, [GCC 4.9.0 supports `<regex>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23476206/47453)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, yeah, as mentioned in the comments:

```
(\d{2,3}(-\d\d) { 2 })
```

should be

```
(\d{2,3}(-\d\d){2})
```

otherwise the `{2}` relates to the space instead of the `(-\d\d)`, and other weird things might possibly happen as well…

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in your regex. Change this:

```
regex r{ R"(\d{2,3}(-\d\d) { 2 })" };
```

To:

```
regex r{ R"(\d{2,3}(-\d\d){2})" };
```