# Regexp to match three patterns

Tags: c++, regex

I have an array of strings where elements can be one of these patterns:

- url `www.example.com`
- hashtag `#followback`
- normal `currentratesoughttogodown`

created from the output `example`, `followback` or `currentratesoughttogodown`.

My current regular expression

```
(?<=www.|\\#)(\\w+)(?=\\.)?
```

matches `www.example.com` and `#followback` in Java but not in `C++` because `C++` doesn't support lookbehind.

**How can I match those three patterns in c++?**

Comment: Hey there. I formatted the text in your question in a clearer way. At first I wasn't sure if you wanted to create those strings or match them. Be as straightforward as you can and make sure that you have a clear, simple, concise question standing out of the text

Answer (score 0):

You can use capturing groups instead. Something like this where your string will reside in the 1st capture group:

```
smatch sm1;
string s1("www.example.com");
regex_search(s1, sm1, regex("^(?:www\\.|\\#)?(.+?)(?:\\.[^.]+?)?$"));
cout << sm1[1] << endl;
```

See [C++ regex string capture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12125057/c-regex-string-capture)